# Is there a way to stop LWC Local Development Server to auto refreshing when component file change?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, force-cli

LWC Local Development Server auto refreshes page whenever any LWC component files change. Sometimes I change JS code but I'm not finished with it, I need to go back to console to refer the console logs/network requests but then I see the page got refreshed and I need to enter the test data all over again. I want to disable this behaviour and want to do the page refresh myself.

I checked the [SFDX CLI Commands reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_lightning.htm#cli_reference_force_lightning) but, I guess, since Local Dev Server is in beta hence there is no mention of `force:lightning:lwc:start` command reference.

Appreciate if anyone could help with this. Thanks!

Comment: In that scenario, why not use push to a scratch org instead, or change IDE settings to only save files when you explicitly tell it? The local server mechanism is intended to automatically handle changes instantly, without the push round-trip so essentially it is either the wrong tool for you or you need to change how you use it.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for your comment. This was actually helpful. Disable IDE's auto save feature. Now the component refreshes only when I explicitly save the files.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, terminal pane right top side open bash and kill terminal will stop local development server

Comment: *bash, to check if it is closed or not, you can restart your local server through terminal

Comment: On Windows, CTRL+` will also open the Terminal directly